# Sql trigger to insert into another table once number is generated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sample

I am very new at `triggers` infact this is my first one and i am rather flustered and confused! I need all the help i can get.

My main aim is the following:

1. Create a Trigger on table Opportunities
2. Generate a quote no in such a format: Q1500/10/2017
3. insert this number that has been generated into another table called UDF

so basically Once a new opportunity is created, the field in the udf table must be inserted only once the quote no is generated. (`insert into the user fields table once the number has been generated`.)

The quote number is no an `autoincrement` number - i basically have created a custom table with one column in that stores the quote no.

Could someone assist me with some sample code so i can get some direction.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Most products have their own versions of triggers.)

Comment: Show us table definitions and your current code attempt. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: I am using SQL Server Triggers.

Comment: as per the above i dont have any code as i dont know where to start. Triggers just baffle me as it all seems so complicated - i am on the forums to try get some direction as to how to start this code off:

cant add table structure as there is not enough characters

Comment: Can you explain the quote number? I am presuming the 10 relates to October, and 2017 the year, but where does Q1500 come from? Is this available once the opportunity has been created, or is it being created somewhere else? Your requirement is quite easy, I think but it is just understanding if you need that creating, or if that is already created.

Comment: @Leonidas199x - The quote number has a prefix of Q and the number 1500 is the number the uote must start from. 10 is October and 2017 the year. so every month the month must be according to the current month and so does the year. The quote number needs to be created or generated once the opportunity is created.

Comment: what i am trying now is to break it up - to first see if i can generate the QT number in my custom table:

I have started my trigger as below and if i insert an opportunity the client_id is inserted but the QT (quote number isnt) probably because i havent set it to be inserted..

Answer (score 0):

Having a staging table to hold ID's is far from ideal, and it can cause issues if for any reason it is not updated. If I were you I would look at alternatives, BUT, as you have requested it, here is one way. 
The code is not exact to your situation, as I without table definitions etc. it cannot be.

1.Create a table to hold your quote number in. In this example it is named 'QuoteRefNo'

2.Create a stored proc to get that number, and increment it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pGetQuoteNumber]

@intQuoteNo INT OUTPUT 

AS BEGIN        
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  @intQuoteNo = QRN.CurrentQuoteNo    
FROM    QuoteRefNo AS QRN

UPDATE  QRN     
SET     QRN.CurrentQuoteNo = QRN.CurrentQuoteNo + 1
FROM    QuoteRefNo AS QRN

END
```

3.Add a trigger to the Opportunity table, so that it creates, and inserts the new quote reference to the quote table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddQuote ON [dbo].[Opportunity]
 AFTER INSERT
 AS
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpInserted') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpInserted
    CREATE TABLE #tmpInserted
    (
        ID          INT             ,
        QuoteRef    NVARCHAR(20)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmpInserted
    (
        ID
    )
    SELECT  I.ID
    FROM    inserted    AS I;

    DECLARE @intMinID       INT             ,
            @intMaxID       INT             ,
            @strMonth       NVARCHAR(2)     , 
            @strYear        NVARCHAR(4)     ,
            @intQuoteNo     INT             ,
            @strQuoteRef    NVARCHAR(20);

    SELECT  @strMonth       =   MONTH(GETDATE())            ,
            @strYear        =   YEAR(GETDATE())             ,
            @intMinID       =   MIN(I.ID)                   ,
            @intMaxID       =   MAX(I.ID)
    FROM    inserted        AS  I


    WHILE(@intMinID <= @intMaxID)

    BEGIN

        EXEC    [dbo].[pGetQuoteNumber] @intQuoteNo = @intQuoteNo OUTPUT;

        UPDATE  TI
        SET     TI.QuoteRef     =   'Q'+CAST(@intQuoteNo AS NVARCHAR(4))+'\'+@strMonth+'\'+@strYear
        FROM    #tmpInserted    AS  TI
        WHERE   TI.ID = @intMinID;

        SELECT @intMinID = @intMinID + 1;

    END


    INSERT INTO Quote
    (
        QuoteRef
    )
    SELECT  TI.QuoteRef
    FROM    #tmpInserted AS TI;

DROP TABLE #tmpInserted;

END
```

Note that, it has to use a loop, to ensure that if more than one record is inserted into the Opportunity table, it can handle that, and create the references with the IDs.

Loops in triggers are to be avoided, and set based solutions should always be preferred. This is something to consider when you are implementing your solution.

Hope that gives you a starting point to resolve the issue you are having.